# how to add foreach array in text input

Tags: php

I have a form in which I enter the `name`, `surname` and function (result one select), I display them with a `foreach` in a table.

I want to add a button to every `foreach` record that will load the first form with the data from the row but I can not.

Thanks for the help!

```
<?php
require_once 'functii/functii.php';
$r = functia();
$options = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $options = $options . "<option>$row[0]</option>";
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <table id="add"><tr><td>Nume:</td><td><input type="text" name="nume"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Prenume:</td><td><input type="text" name="prenume"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Functia:</td><td><select name="functia"><?php echo $options; ?></select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Activ:</td><td><input type="radio" name="activ"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="adaugare" value="Adauga"/><input type="submit" name="modificare" value="Modifica"/></td></tr></table> 
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['adaugare'])) {
    require_once 'functii/functii.php';
    $n = $_POST['nume'];
    $p = $_POST['prenume'];
    $f = $_POST['functia'];
    $r = adaug_utilizator($n, $p, $f);
}

require_once 'functii/functii.php';
$utilizatori = grid_utilizatori();
if (count($utilizatori) == 0) {
    print 'Nu sunt utilizatori adaugati';
} else {
    ?>
    <table id="view">
        <thead><tr><th colspan="4">Utilizatori adaugati</th></tr>
            <tr><th>Nume</th><th>Prenume</th><th>Functia</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                
            <?php
            foreach ($utilizatori as $utilizator) {
                print "<tr>";
                print "<td>" . $utilizator['nume'] . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . $utilizator['prenume'] . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . $utilizator['denumire'] . "</td>";
                print "<td><input type='submit' name='modifica' value='Modifica'></td>";
                print "</tr>";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['modifica'])) {
                $_POST['nume'] = $utilizator['nume'];
                $_POST['prenume'] = $utilizator['prenume'];
                $_POST['functia'] = $utilizator['denumire'];
            }
            ?> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please specify your question and show us your attempts, cause we do not write code for you! If you need someone to write those buttons for you, then rent a developer.

Comment: I created buttons but I can not get the data associated with the buttons in the form inputs

Comment: Please [edit] your existing question for relevant informations :)

Comment: You have given the same `name` to button, that's why your post data do not get relevant data. If you want data to be posted based on which button click, please give different `name` to each button to differentiate whihc button is clicked

Comment: I want the button Modifica to add the data to the initial form with which the information is entered into the database

Answer (score 0):

You can execute loop as follows:

```
<?php
foreach($utilizatori as $index => $utilizator){
?>
<input type='submit' name='modifica<?php echo ($index+1);?>' value='Modifica' class="clickBtn"></td>
<?php 
}
?>
```

with above loop name attribute will be as modifica1, modifica2 etc.

Now, you want to fill information based on button clicked to the form shown at your top of code, I think so.

For this, you can use jQuery:

```
$('.clickBtn').click(function(e){
   var buttonOfRowClicked = $(this).attr('name');
   var rowNumber = buttonOfRowClicked.substr(8);  // It will get 1,2,3 etc table row.

   $('input[name=nume]').val($(tr:nth-child(rowNumber) td:nth-child(1).val());
   $('input[name=prenume]').val($(tr:nth-child(rowNumber) td:nth-child(2).val());   //similarly fill other variables.
});
```

I have not check the code by executing. It is overview for you to run your code. I think idea is sufficient for you for direction how should your code works.